# “Diff” an image using ImageMagick

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, diff, difference

How can I get the difference between two images? I have the original image. Someone has written on an exact duplicate of the original image. Now, I need to compare the original to the written on image and extract just the writing in image format.

Example: I have a picture of a house. Someone took a copy and wrote “Hello!” on the copy. I want to somehow compare the two pictures, remove the house, and be left with an image of the words “Hello!”.

Is this possible with ImageMagick? I know there are ways to get the statistical difference between images, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Try [this section](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/) of the ImageMagick usage guide!

Comment: I know this question is about ImageMagick, but I just had to include a link to [Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) for the "causual" searcher who may be after an agnostic solution.

Comment: Does anyone know of a tool that will compare 2 images by subtracting the pixels of the second image, from the first? I'd prefer not writing my own.

Comment: Imagemagick 7 has perceptual hash, a technique using invariant image moments. it's nice in the sense that it hashes the same even after rotation, barrel distortion, resize, gamma change, noise introduction, watermarking...

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/209517/does-diff-exist-for-images

Comment: @v.oddou, I tried IM7 perceptual hash on two images, one image is simple translation of another (size, orientation, colorspace, and shape remained the same). The command is `/compare -metric phash Image1.png Image2.png null:`. PHash was different. I compared with a different image and PHash different in similar amount. I didn't test with rotation, distortion, resize, and other transformations, because it did not produce what you claimed with a simpler transformation. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BReddy I have no idea, I never used it. I just repeated the claims of the research papers and imagemagick documents. I'm not surprised that it doesn't work in practice, it's a classic to pretend something incredible and then it flops.

Comment: @v.oddou, Thanks. I read docs and did few more tests. It appears to perform badly with line drawings which are very sparsely populated and extremely low pixel density. Looks like pixel density is the key in PHASH identifying similarity.

Answer (score 382, accepted):

My own favorites are these two:

```
 compare image1 image2 -compose src diff.png
 compare image1 image2 -compose src diff.pdf
```

The only difference between the 2 commands above: the first one shows the visual difference between the two images as a PNG file, the second one as a PDF.

The resulting diff file displays all pixels which are different in red color. The ones which are unchanged appear white.

Short and sweet.

Note, your images need ***not*** be the same type. You can even mix JPEG, TIFF, PNG -- under one condition: the images should be of the same size (image dimension in pixels). The output format is determined by the output filename's extension.

Should you, for some reason, need a higher resolution than the default one (72 dpi) -- then just add an appropriate `-density` parameter:

```
 compare -density 300 image1 image2 -compose src diff.jpeg
```

---

### Illustrated examples

Here are a few illustrations of results for variations of the above command. **Note: the two files compared were even** ***PDF files***, so it works with these too (as long as they are 1-pagers)!

---

**Left:** Image with text       **Center:** Original image      **Right:** Differences (=text) in red pixels.
[image: Red difference pixels only; identical pixels are white]

```
compare \
        porsche-with-scratch.pdf  porsche-original.pdf \
       -compose src \
        diff-compose-default.pdf
```

This is the same command I suggested earlier above.

---

**Left:** Image with text      **Center:** Original image      **Right:** Differences in 'seagreen' pixels.
[image: Seagreen difference pixels only; identical pixels are white]

```
compare \
        porsche-with-scratch.pdf  porsche-original.pdf \
       -compose src \
       -highlight-color seagreen \
        diff-compose-default.pdf
```

This command adds a parameter to make the difference pixels 'seagreen' instead of the default red.

---

**Left:** Image with text       **Center:** Original image       **Right:** Blue diffs (but w. some context background)
[image: Blue difference pixels only; first of the compared images as a lightened-up background]l

```
compare \
        porsche-with-scratch.pdf  porsche-original.pdf \
       -highlight-color blue \
        diff-compose-default.pdf
```

This command removes the `-compose src` part -- the result is the default behavior of `compare` which keeps as a lightened background the first one of the 2 diffed images. (This time with added parameter to make the diff pixels appear in blue.)

Comment: I am not able to understand where this compare cli came from? Is it part of imagebrick? available on windows?

Comment: @Krishnom: There's no such thing as 'imagebrick'. Do you mean ImageMagick?

Comment: @Krishnom: The question explicitely asked about an ImageMagick solution. Part of ImageMagick's v6.x software suite had a separate CLI tool called *`'compare'`*. For v7.x of ImageMagick you should run *`'magick compare'`* instead.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for correcting that (imagebrick -> imageMagick).  I will give it a try. I am also looking tool to compare bulk images. Thanks for the help again

Comment: @Krishnom: I do not know what a "bulk image" is. But I still bet that the ImageMagick suite of tools can do what you want.

Comment: I had no idea this existed. This is great! I was doing some visual regression testing with puppeteer and was perplexed why I was never getting the same results for a certain page. This allowed me to easily find the diff! Thanks!

Answer (score 81):

While `compare` does a good job for many applications, I found that sometimes I prefer a different approach, particularly when comparing images which are mostly grayscale:

```
convert '(' file1.png -flatten -grayscale Rec709Luminance ')' \
        '(' file2.png -flatten -grayscale Rec709Luminance ')' \
        '(' -clone 0-1 -compose darken -composite ')' \
        -channel RGB -combine diff.png
```

The idea is follows: convert both `file1.png` and `file2.png` to grayscale. Then trat the first as the red channel of the resulting image, the second as the green channel. The blue channel is formed from these two using the `darken` compose operator, which essentially means taking the minimum.

So things which are white in both images stay white. Things which are black in both images stay black. Things which are white in the first image but black in the second turn red, and things which are white in the second but black in the first turn green.

The result gives you a nicely color-coded image where you can easily associate green with the first input and red with the second. Here is an example where I'm using this to compare the output from LaTeX against that from [KaTeX](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) (before I [fixed some bug](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/pull/295) to make this better):

[image]

You can combine the approaches, using `compare` to see *where* something changed and then using the above to see in more detail *how* it changed.

Comment: Nice! I needed some interaction so I replicated your method in Gimp. For reference: 1) load images as layers, 2) Color -> Desaturate both layers, 3) remove alpha channels from both layers in the Layers tab, 4) select the G + B channels on one layer, select all and clear the channels with black color, the same with the R + B channels on the second layer, 4) set Screen mode for the upper layer in the Layers tab.

Comment: @Palmstrom: Thanks! I originally did these image comparisons using Gimp myself, but I did so using [the “grain extract” layer mode](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html#idp14580272) directly on the input images, so common areas would end up gray, while the diff would be black in one direction and white in the other. Harder to read, but quicker to generate, and it can contain color information. I guess you would match my command even more closely if you were using “darken only” instead of “screen”, and color unused channels white instead of black.

Comment: *Some* PDF inputs result in an inverted image after grayscale conversion for some reason. Using `-colorspace gray` instead of `-grayscale Rec709Luminance` fixes that, but this messes up the composition. Add `-respect-parentheses` as the first option to `convert` to take care of that.

Comment: Here's a script to visually diff two PDFs page-by-page using this method: https://gist.github.com/brechtm/891de9f72516c1b2cbc1. It outputs one JPG for each page of the PDFs in a `pdfdiff` directory and additionally prints the numbers of the pages which differ between the two PDFs.

Comment: In ImageMagick v6.7.7-10 it seems `-grayscale` is not supported, I had to use `-colorspace gray` as @BrechtMachiels suggested

Comment: Very nice! For me (ImageMagick 7.1.0-29) `-flatten` did weird not useful things (it seemed to revert to an uncropped version of my source image, which doesn't make sense), but it worked perfectly fine without it. Possibly only useful if you have a transparency layer in your png? I also swapped the order of the input files so red means "removed in file2" and green means "added in file2", which is more intuitive in my mind.

Answer (score 5):

From ImageMagick 6.3.4, you can use [`-compose ChangeMask`](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#changemask) (see also ["Removing a Known Background"](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#known_bgnd) and following sections).
For example, using IM7 and these images `stone.png`, `diamond_ore.png`, and `netherrack.png`:
[image: stone.png]
[image: diamond_ore.png]
[image: netherrack.png]

`magick diamond_ore.png stone.png -fuzz 15% -compose ChangeMask -composite diamond_ore_overlay.png` gives:
[image: diamond_ore_overlay.png]

Then `magick netherrack.png diamond_ore_overlay.png -composite nether_diamond_ore.png` gives:
[image: nether_diamond_ore.png]
(In one command: `magick netherrack.png \( diamond_ore.png stone.png -fuzz 15% -compose ChangeMask -composite +compose \) -composite nether_diamond_ore.png`)