# ImageMagick making different images on Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I need a batch process for making mobile images and decided to use ImageMagick, but unfortunately one of my requirements is that the images produced are the same across OS's, since I'm sending them back and forth between my local system (Windows) and the server (Linux).  It seems however whenever I call

```
convert test.jpg -resize 25% test-small.jpg
```

the process creates different images on both machines.  I know this because when I use checksum the values aren't exactly the same.

Does anyone know of any reason why this would happen?  And maybe some way around it, either via using a different executable or passing in a parameter that would produce the same images across OS's?

Comment: an option is to install a linux virtual machine in your computer, and do the conversions in linux

Comment: I've thought of that, you mean like Cygwin?  I've been burned by it many times, so I'm really looking for something that spans while being in their separate environment.  Strangely when I use jpegtran to optimize my jpegs, it creates the same image for both OS's.  I wonder if it has to do with losslessness.  I'm not an image processing buff, so this stuff is new to me.

Comment: I mean using virtualbox or vmplayer, with both you can install linux in windows and run both at the same time.  e.g. download an ubuntu iso, and create a new virtual machine. you need to specify the amount of RAM, HD space, and the ubuntu iso image location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The files have more than the pixels in them -- If you are going to compare the images, write a checksum that works on just the decoded pixel data.  That will at least tell you if the images would look the same.  The internals of the file could be different because of a lot of factors.
2. Resizing is dependent on float arithmetic and you can't count on that to be the same across machines.  So instead of using just a checksum, you might want to see if each pixel is within a tolerance from the associated one in the other file.

Take a look at these links:

- http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.phpied.com/image-diff/

Answer (score 1):

JPEG algorithms are non-deterministic. There is no way to ensure that the same image will be generated across two systems, or even between two invocations on the same system.

Comment: This is also happening with PNG, is the algorithm similar for that as well?

Comment: @jimlamiell: for pngs, try optipng or pngcrush to remove as much metadata as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on 'checksum' or 'md5sum' or similar to compare two images isn't a wise choice. This can only verify if the files are indeed identical. However, if you have different results, this could be caused by just one byte in some random meta data value being different (like a simple timestamp), while there's no pixel difference at all.

To discover the pixel differences between two images, you can use ImageMagick's `compare` like this:

```
compare  image1.jpg  image2.jpg  delta.jpg
```

For colored input images, the resulting *delta.jpg* willl use *image1.jpb* as a light-gray background and display the differences in red color. To get a red+white delta image without the light-gray background, use

```
compare  image1.jpg  image2.jpg  -compose src  delta.jpg
```

Examples images of this techniq can be found **here**:

- [**ImageMagick: “Diff” an Image**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362152/359307)
  **Left:** Image with text       **Center:** Original image      **Right:** Differences (=text) in red pixels.
  [image: Red difference pixels only; identical pixels are white]