# compare images in two different directories and identify best match

Tags: image, bash, compare, imagemagick

I am looking for an easiest way to compare images in two different directories and identify the best match. After finding the best match, save images into a new directory with the same name of images that are in source directory. For example

```
/path/to/src/img1, img2, img3.......

/path/to/dest/img11, img22, img33.....

/path/to/target/img1, img2, img3....
```

I did some research online i found `compare` command using imagemagick but i am quit new and couldn't figure out how it will work with set of multiple images in two different directories and name the images with respect to names of `src` directory.
Please ask me if i couldn't explain you my problem briefly.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends some extent on *how* you expect the images to differ. An image that is identical to another except flipped about one axis would have an identical min/mean/max and standard deviation but maybe no two pixels the same. Two images shot with a slightly different exposure may be visually almost indistinguishable from each other, yet have no two pixels the same.

Comment: In my case I have images taken at same camera angle and their size is same but one with projection of patterns and other without projection.

Comment: Can you show samples?

Comment: For your reference i have uploaded some images and all other are same like these. Please check the link.
https://www.mediafire.com/?aizx2z1u76z0db9

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hello, actually it didn't work for me. May be I couldn't explain you well about my problem. Here I found an another question same like I asked and answer 2 well suits to my problem. But it is not giving me 100% results. It is eliminating some of pictures in the folder and finding wrong match for 2 or 3 pictures sometimes.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649876/search-for-similar-images-with-different-filenames-in-two-directories?rq=1]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649876/search-for-similar-images-with-different-filenames-in-two-directories?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a normalised cross-correlation between each image in the current directory and each image in the other directory and find which one has the highest correlation like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Work out list of source and destination files
SRC=(*.jpg)
DST=(../wop/*.jpg)

# Ensure output directory exists
TGT=result
[ ! -d "$TGT" ] && mkdir "$TGT" 

for a in ${SRC[@]}; do
   nearest=0
   for b in ${DST[@]}; do
      # Perform normalised cross-correlation with each image in other directory
      result=$(convert "$a" "$b" -metric ncc -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:)
      # Convert result to rounded integer percentage
      percent=$(echo "scale=0;$result*100/1" | bc)
      echo DEBUG compare $a with $b: $percent
      # Update if this one is nearer than previous nearest
      [ $percent -gt $nearest ] && { nearest=$percent; friend=$b; }
   done
   echo cp "$friend" "$TGT/$a" 
done
```

**Output**

```
./go
DEBUG compare 00000000.jpg with ../wop/00000007.jpg: 22
DEBUG compare 00000000.jpg with ../wop/00000014.jpg: 17
DEBUG compare 00000000.jpg with ../wop/00000015.jpg: 77
cp ../wop/00000015.jpg result/00000000.jpg
DEBUG compare 00000001.jpg with ../wop/00000007.jpg: 37
DEBUG compare 00000001.jpg with ../wop/00000014.jpg: 71
DEBUG compare 00000001.jpg with ../wop/00000015.jpg: 32
cp ../wop/00000014.jpg result/00000001.jpg
DEBUG compare 00000005.jpg with ../wop/00000007.jpg: 77
DEBUG compare 00000005.jpg with ../wop/00000014.jpg: 36
DEBUG compare 00000005.jpg with ../wop/00000015.jpg: 31
cp ../wop/00000007.jpg result/00000005.jpg
```

Comment: how can we say that these are similar images? I didn't understand from the output.

Comment: The decimal number is the normalised cross correlation - the nearer it is to 1 the more similar the images, so 000000.jpg is most similar to 000015.jpg, and 00001.jpg is most similar to 000014.jpg.

Comment: Ok thank you. I understood the logic but how can I use this info to copy images from src directory to target directory.

Comment: Thank you sir, your script is working but after so many tries I am still unable to copy images from directory "wop" into another directory with names of same images in "wp" directory.

Comment: Aha, I think I understand what you want now and have changed the code - please try again.