# How to lighten an image using ImageMagick like when using compare?

Tags: imagemagick

As you see in the answer [“Diff” an image using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362152/1366368), the "delta" image is somehow lightened:

[image]

How would I lighten an image just like that using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you would like to lighten 2nd image so you get 3rd but without text. So from command line this should give same results:

```
convert porsche.png -fill white -colorize 80%  porshe_light.png
```

Answer (score 4):

To get ***exactly*** the same type of output, just use exactly the same command as in the answer ("['Diff an image using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362152/1366368)") you quoted.

Just compare the image in question with itself:

```
convert wizard: -frame 1 wizard.png
compare wizard.png wizard.png delta.png
```

will give you these images, original (left) and "delta" (right):

[image] [image]

### Update

Incidentally, I had suspected that @rostok's answer would somehow not use the correct parameter value for his `-colorize` operator. But his `80%` happens to be exactly correct, as can be seen by the output below:

```
convert wizard.png -colorize 80% wiz-light.png
```

[image]

<sup>*(Of course I had no choice to upvote @rostok's answer too...  :-)        Actually, it is even a better answer than this one, because it hints to the OP that he could change the `-colorize` parameter, if he wants to change the degree of the operator.)*</sup>