# How can I unittest whether PDF files have been generated correctly?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pdf, pytest

I write a small python library that uses matplotlib and seaborn to draw charts, and I wonder how I can test whether the charts look like what I actually want.

Thus, given a reference pdf file which I declared as correct, how would I automatically check whether it equals a dynamically generated file with dummy data?

I assume that it's not reliable to hash the file due to timestamps etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Use [diff-pdf](https://vslavik.github.io/diff-pdf/)
- Convert it to an image (e.g. using ImageMagick) and use [PerceptualDiff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/)
- Get the data out of the PDF somehow ([PyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/) maybe?) and compare that
- Use something (PyPDF2? [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)?) to patch the header information (like timestamps) to the point the files are equal and compare hashes

Comment: As today, 0 positive votes and 0 negative votes. I am always surprised when I see an accepted answer that does not get a single vote. If it solved the problem, it must also be vote worthy

Answer (score 2):

For use with regression testing, I have written [`diffpdf.sh`](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/69d6d5329d674d77c2749bf547230e497a83ea29/tests_regression/helpers/diffpdf.sh) to perform a page-by-page visual diff for PDFs. It makes use of ImageMagick and the Poppler PDF utilities `pdftoppm` and `pdfinfo`.

`diffpdf.sh` will output a non-zero return code if the PDFs do not display identically and print the page numbers for the pages that differ, along with a number that reflects how much the pages differ. A visual diff image for each page is also saved to the `pdfdiff` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: diffpdf.sh fidle_1.pdf file_2.pdf

# requirements:
# - ImageMagick
# - Poppler's pdftoppm and pdfinfo tools (works with 0.18.4 and 0.41.0,
#                                         fails with 0.42.0)

DIFFDIR="pdfdiff"                        # directory to place diff images in
MAXPROCS=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)    # number of parallel processes

pdf_file1=$1
pdf_file2=$2

function diff_page {
    # based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/33673440/438249
    pdf_file1=$1
    pdf_file2=$2
    page_number=$3
    page_index=$(($page_number - 1))

    (cat $pdf_file1 | pdftoppm -f $page_number -singlefile -gray - | convert - miff:- ; \
     cat $pdf_file2 | pdftoppm -f $page_number -singlefile -gray - | convert - miff:- ) | \
    convert - \( -clone 0-1 -compose darken -composite \) \
            -channel RGB -combine $DIFFDIR/$page_number.jpg

    if (($? > 0)); then
        echo "Problem running pdftoppm or convert!"
        exit 1
    fi
    grayscale=$(convert pdfdiff/$page_number.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format "%[fx:mean]" info:)
    if [ "$grayscale" != "0" ]; then
        echo "page $page_number ($grayscale)"
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}

function num_pages {
    pdf_file=$1

    pdfinfo $pdf_file | grep "Pages:" | awk '{print $2}'
}

function minimum {
    echo $(( $1 < $2 ? $1 : $2 ))
}

# guard agains accidental deletion of files in the root directory
if [ -z "$DIFFDIR" ]; then
    echo "DIFFDIR needs to be set!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Running $MAXPROCS processes in parallel"

pdf1_num_pages=$(num_pages $pdf_file1)
pdf2_num_pages=$(num_pages $pdf_file2)

min_pages=$(minimum $pdf1_num_pages $pdf2_num_pages)

if [ "$pdf1_num_pages" -ne "$pdf2_num_pages" ]; then
    echo "PDF files have different lengths ($pdf1_num_pages and $pdf2_num_pages)"
    rc=1
fi

if [ -d "$DIFFDIR" ]; then
    rm -f $DIFFDIR/*
else
    mkdir $DIFFDIR
fi


# get exit status from subshells (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29535256/438249)
function wait_for_processes {
    local rc=0

    while (( "$#" )); do
        # wait returns the exit status for the process
        if ! wait "$1"; then
            rc=1
        fi
        shift
    done
    return $rc
}

function howmany() {
    echo $#
}

rc=0
pids=""
for page_number in `seq 1 $min_pages`;
do
    diff_page $pdf_file1 $pdf_file2 $page_number &
    pids+=" $!"
    if [ $(howmany $pids) -eq "$MAXPROCS" ]; then
        if ! wait_for_processes $pids; then
            rc=1
        fi
        pids=""
    fi
done

if ! wait_for_processes $pids; then
    rc=1
fi

exit $rc
```

**EDIT:** An improved version of this script, written in Python can be found [here](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/blob/stable/tests_regression/helpers/diffpdf.py).