# Discard images from a group of similar images

Tags: python, node.js, linux, image, ffmpeg

I am generating images (thumbnails) from a video every 3 seconds. Now I need to discard/remove all the similar images. Is there a way I could this?

I generate thumbnails using [FFMPEG](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video). I read about various image-diff solutions like [given in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132749/diff-an-image-using-imagemagick), but I do not want to do this manually. How and what parameters should be considered that could tell if a particular image is similar to other images present.

Comment: Try the [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the Structural Similarity Index between images and based on the score keep or discard an image.  There are other measures you can use, but basically a method that returns a score.  Try PIL or OpenCV
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html?highlight=difference
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment my idea on your problem, so i will just go ahead and post it as an answer in hope of helping you.

I am quite confused about the term "similar" but since you are reffering on video frames i am going to assume that you want to avoid having "similar" frames that have been captured because of poor camera movement. If that's the case you might want to consider using salient point descriptors.

To be more specific you can detect salient points (using for instance [Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_Corner_Detector)) and then use a point descriptor algorithm (such as [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features)) and discard the frames that have been found to have "too many" similar points with a pre-selected frame.

Keep in mind that in order for the above process to be successful, the frames must be as sharp as possible, i guess you don't want to extract as a thubnail a blurred frame anyway. So applying a blurred images detection might be useful in your case.