# overlap misplaced images for the maximum similarity and find difference using clustering techniques rather then pixel to pixel comparison

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, imagemagick, hierarchical-clustering

I am working for image comparison which are 99% same amd 1% difference. 
I am capturing Image of the print using Vision camera (mounted over a fix stand). 
I tried all Image comparison algorithm : opencv, ImageMagic, skimage. (result was 80 to 90 percent accuracy)

link : [“Diff” an image using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132749/diff-an-image-using-imagemagick)

link : [How can I quantify difference between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images)

I implemented all the above solution from the above question to find the difference, but the problem with above algorithm is, they work pixel to pixel. non of this algorithm provided a smarter approach for image comparison.

After capturing image of two different prints of same type I do the following steps for image comparison:

my code for overlapping misplaced images for the maximum similarity is :

code for image aliment :

```html
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('./photo/image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale

retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray,cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

mx_rect = (0,0,0,0)      
mx_area = 0
for cnt in contours:
    arect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    area = arect[1][0]*arect[1][1]
    if area > mx_area:
        mx_rect, mx_area = arect, area

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
# cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),8)
roi_1 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
cv2.imwrite('./test/Image_rec.jpg', roi_1)

print("shape of cnt: {}".format(cnt.shape))
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
print("rect: {}".format(rect))

box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
width = int(rect[1][0])
height = int(rect[1][1])

src_pts = box.astype("float32")
dst_pts = np.array([[0, height-1],
                    [0, 0],
                    [width-1, 0],
                    [width-1, height-1]], dtype="float32")
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (width, height))

cv2.imwrite('./crop_Image_rortate.jpg', warped)
```

Above code gives the required image i.e. it tries to alien image, it crop the required image, but some time it fails as well (2/10, 2 out of 10 fails).

Once the image is crop, I compare it to find the difference using clustering techniques. my code for comparison is as follow :

```html
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy.misc as smp

f1= './Image_1.png'
f2= './Image_2.png'
im1 = Image.open(f1)
im2 = Image.open(f2)
img1= cv2.imread(f1)
img2= cv2.imread(f2)

# print (img1.shape)
# print (img2.shape)

w_1= img1.shape[0]
h_1= img1.shape[1]
W_1 = w_1-1
H_1 = h_1-1
c = 0
X=[]
Y=[]
R=[]
G=[]
B=[]

rgb = im1.convert('RGB')
rgb2 = im2.convert('RGB')
for x in range(H_1):
    for y in range(W_1):
        
        r1, g1, b1, = rgb.getpixel((x,y))
        t1= r1+g1+b1
        i = x
        j = y
        r2, g2, b2, = rgb2.getpixel((i,j))
        t2=r2+g2+b2
        d= t1-t2

        if d in range (-150,150):
            # print (d)
            pass
        else:
            c = c + 1
            if (c == 1):
                z=y
                
            elif (y == z+1 ):
                # print (x,y)
                i = x+1
                j = y+1
                r2, g2, b2, = rgb2.getpixel((i,j))
                t2=r2+g2+b2
                d= t1-t2

                if d in range (-150,150):
                    # print (d)
                    pass
                    
                else:
                    X.append(x)
                    Y.append(y)
                    R.append(r1)
                    G.append(g1)
                    B.append(b1)

            z=y
            z1=y  # to make group of 2. 


try: 
    data = np.zeros( (h_1,w_1,3), dtype=np.uint8 )

    length = len(X)
    print ("total pixel difference : ",length)

    for i in range(length):
        data[X[i],Y[i]] = [R[i],G[i],B[i]]

    img = Image.fromarray( data, 'RGB' )
    img.save('./test/new.png')
    img.show()
except:
    print ("Error during image creation. ")
```

above code tries to ***implement clustering base image comparison*** and it is also slow.
comparison skips the first pixel as difference even it is a difference for every row. it will look for major difference only.

But still the problem remains same, pixel to pixel comparison.

**Is there a proper clustering technique which will target the proper difference.**

**I don't want to do pixel to pixel image comparison, as it provide incorrect result for me.**

I am also open to other techniques for image comparison, If available and not listed.

Image Sample :

Image 1:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP3CY.jpg)

Image 2:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv9gF.jpg)

Accepted Output:
[Accepted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkdGJ.jpg)

output after difference :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEmmq.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps if you post links to two of your images, we can see what the issue is and also suggest solutions.

Comment: @fmw42 added sample images.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Your accepted output is smaller than your two images and does not show the difference. Please clarify. What is wrong with your difference output. That looks like what you would get from using Imagemagick compare.

Comment: @fmw42 I am trying to find the **defect** during print. print of one type multiple times. The accepted output can be of any size, but it should hight-light the correct defect.