# Is it possible to compare two images using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to compare two images using Robot Framework? I tried one solution using OpenCV that compares two images, but it's getting difficult to write something specific to Robot Framework.

Comment: You are on the right track when you started with OpenCV. If you are running RF with Python, you should write a new keyword with Python.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, I think I will do my stuff that way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot framework itself doesn't have any such feature. However, it's possible to write a custom keyword to do it. I worked on a team a few years ago that built some keywords based on the [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) library. You can either have the keywords import the imagemagick library itself, or use the imagemagick cli.

For more information see [“Diff” an image using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132749/diff-an-image-using-imagemagick)